# Creating a loop to manipulate a table

Tags: matlab

I have a a table with target temperature and actual temperature like this (table1):

```
   Time    Target    actual    diffrence
   ____    ______    ______    _________

   1       40        40.2      0.2      
   2       40          41        1      
   3       40        40.3      0.3
```

I want to create a table that only contains the rows with a difference <= 0.5.

So the goal should look like this (table2):

```
   Time    Target    actual
   ____    ______    ______

   1       40        40.2
   3       40        40.3
```

I don't know how to create a loop that solves my problem.
I tried to create an if-loop within a for loop:

```
for n = 1:3
    if difference(n) <= 0.5
        table2 = table(table1.Time(n), table1.Target(n), table1.actual(n))
    end
end
```

But when i execute, my table3 consists of only the third row.

```
   3       40        40.3
```

Can somebody please help me create the loop? (Maybe my loop always overwrites table3 and only saves the last iteration?)

Comment: What if row 2 had `actual = 40.8` ? It's different from row 1 but not row 3, should it be kept in the result ? What I am trying to say is that you need to explain what you mean by difference.

Comment: @SomeGuy. It's pretty unambiguous: there's a column called `difference`.

Comment: @ some guy: I'm not sure if I know what you mean. If actual was 40.8, the difference would be greater than 0.5, so it should be excluded.

Comment: @SomeGuy. `difference` is just `actual - Target`.

Comment: My bad I went full robot on it and didn't realize that you have a column named `diffrence` , I was under the impression that you are trying to check for difference in `actual` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem is correct. The statement in the loop just sets the value of `table2` to be the latest row that meets the criterion.

You do not need to use loops for this at all. Create a boolean mask based on the `difference` column:

```
mask = table1{:, 4} > 0.5;
```

You can then select a subset of the entire table using the mask as an index:

```
table2 = table1{mask, 1:3};
```

You could even combine the two lines into one:

```
table2 = table1{table1{:, 4} > 0.5, 1:3};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem in such a short time with just  two or one line of code!

Comment: No worries. Keep in mind that you should try to vectorize as much as possible in MATLAB. `for` loops have their purpose of course, but operations such as this should usually be done with careful indexing.

Comment: Will keep in mind. Maybe you could show me where I went wrong with my loop? I want to learn to create loops too but could not find a matching example.

Comment: You would have to assign the row to a new row in `table2` instead of overwriting `table2` itself: `table2{end + 1, :} = table1{n, 1:3};`.